# variations in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, variations

I am using sharepoint 2013 for the development of a multilingual webapplication

I have a task I want the calendar list created on the source site   to  be propagated and synched with the target site .  but the calendar list does not have a variation option available , Is it possible to run variations on task lists and calendar lists, if it  is not possible , is there any other work around through which this functionality can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

its not possible

More description

I didn't Find a way until now to work around for calendar and task 
calendar maybe for culture issue so its not available 
when I found a way I will update this post