# Variations, Lists Propagations

Tags: 2013, list, variations, language

I have a source site and a target site.

Why can not some lists be propagated through target sites? 
I mean, if I create a *Links or Events* list in the source site I do not see the Variations ribbon, so I can not propagate list.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the lists you want to be propagated to target sites excepting Task Lists and Calendar Lists.

Can you be more descriptive to know what it is happening?

Comment: Exactly, I can propagate (by clicking on the ribbon) all the kind of list but not calendar and links (I do not have the variation ribbon)

Answer (score 0):

No, I tried this myself and it seems the Variations option [in the ribbon banner] doesn't come up for Links, Task Lists and Calendar Lists. It seems like it's not supported.

I can see some more folks have faced this issue: [variations in sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/80393/35883)